# Possible to put an algorithm inside a \begin{itemize}?

Tags: itemize, algorithms, algorithmicx

Is it possible to put an algorithm inside a \begin{itemize} as one of the \items?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just don't use a floating environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b} 
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$ 
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0} 
\State $a\gets b$ 
\State $b\gets r$ 
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$ 
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile} 
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b} 
\EndProcedure 
\end{algorithmic} 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```